# How to get URLs from text properly that will not raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url)) error?

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests

I used following code to get links from tweets which are stored in a DataFrame

```
column = ['tweet_text']
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names = column, header = None)
df["tweet_text"]=df["tweet_text"].astype(str)
pattern = r'(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)'
df['links']= df["tweet_text"].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

I am using following code to extract actual links from shortened ones give from twitter and page content of each link as well

```
url_list = list(df['links'])
actual_list =[]
HTML_content = []
import requests
for link in url_list:
    response = requests.get(str(link.encode("ascii")))
    actual_url = response.text
    response = requests.get(str(actual_url.encode("ascii")))
    actual_list.append(actual_url)
    HTML_content.append(response.content)

df["actual_url"] = actual_list
df["HTML"] = HTML_content
```

until yesterday this code was doing what it intended to do. But when I scraped other tweets today and tried to get information it is giving

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-fc52700ad1a7> in <module>()
      6 session.trust_env = False
      7 for link in url_list:
----> 8     response = requests.get(str(link.encode("ascii")))
      9     actual_url = response.text
     10     response = requests.get(str(actual_url.encode("ascii")))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in get_adapter(self, url)
    726 
    727         # Nothing matches :-/
--> 728         raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
    729 
    730     def close(self):

InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "b'https : // t. co / emPZ7VNT4E'"
```

Now I know the problem is with the link and error message shows that its double quotes and `b`. As most other solutions to this problem tell to remove extra characters but I have checked link there is no such extra characters(or at least that's what `df['links']` is showing) and secondly I need to perform this operation on daily basis, which means I will not be able to tackle this problem every day. Can someone tell me how can I resolve this problem?

PS: I added spaces in shortened link because stackoverflow won't allow to post such links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use beautiful soup to extract all links from source code and validators module to validate whether url is valid or not.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import validators, requests

r = requests.get(source_url)
b = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
valid_urls = list(filter(validators.url, map(lambda x: x.get('href',''), b.findAll('a'))))
```

Here the BeautifulSoup provides bs4.element.tags of all anchor tags, from there we map each tags to href strings (list). Then filter will remove all invalid urls.

Comment: If I use as `url_list` argument to `requests.get` it gives `InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https ://t . co / emPZ7VNT4 E',...` and if I iterate over each link separately it gives `ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ow . ly', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:` error

Comment: Error remains same when I iterate over each link even using proxies pool

Comment: here is [link](https://gist.github.com/abidddd/a3fcf2d18d2554cecff7c1f71566ae63)  to dataset if you want to try it by yourself

Comment: InvalidSchema Error is due to space present in your url,
ConnectionError: may occur if the site isn't available. Well use exception handling, try except to ignore all unavailable links.

Comment: Well try not encoding the urls, on contrast decode them to python <class 'str'>, that was also causing your InvalidSchema Error